# How to change the password to an account?

Tags: accounts, private-key, password, keystore

The private key of an owned Ethereum account is encrypted with a password and kept in a so-called key file. How can I change this password?

Comment: Depends on the client you are using, geth?

Comment: You cannot change it. Create a new account and transfer the fund from old account to new account.

Comment: @5chdn I usually use geth / Mist, but can use any other tool if that helps.

Comment: @yoregis You suggestion is very restrictive. What if your address has some privileges, assets or tokens assigned to it?

Comment: yes, you're right. I will try this for geth, concerning updating an account https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#updating-an-existing-account

Answer (score 13):

Simply use geth as indicated in the [github wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#account-update):

> #### Account update
>
> ```
> $ geth account update a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b
> Unlocking account a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b | Attempt 1/3
> Passphrase:
> 0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b
> Account 'a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b' unlocked.
> Please give a new password. Do not forget this password.
> Passphrase:
> Repeat Passphrase:
> 0xa94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b
> ```

Comment: If I forget the passphrase but I have the keystore file, is there any way to recover the passphrase?

Comment: @RameshPareek non, sorry.